# Visual Studio 2010 issue properties not updating when clicking on a control (gridview)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

My hard drive died recently so I had to install visual studio 2010 all over again. With this version of VS anytime I click on a control (like text box or gridview) the properties section doesn't update. Even when i right click on the control and click view properties it doesn't update ... The only way i can get the properties tab to update is by building the project (but i have to do this every time i want to view properties of a control). I have uninstalled and reinstalled (VS 2010 and SP1) but neither have had an effect on the issue.

I have also tried turning off the add-ons as i thought this might affect performance (but not joy). I also have Visual Studio 2008 and this works perfectly.

Its like as if the application isn't refreshing or something ? And the build is forcing a refresh ?

Comment: Ctrl+W P  .. you can get the Opton in VIEW

Comment: Nope, the properties window is open but it is just blank. Nothing in the dropdown list either. Only gets populated when i run Build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well turns out it was McAfee Virus Scanner !!!!!!!

So annoying, i turned On-Access Virus Scanning OFF and everything worked :-)

Unfortunately the On-Access Virus Scanning turns itself back on after a few hours so I have added Visual Studio and my files location to the exclusion list and this works !

Hopefully someone else will find this useful